# asp.net + Bootstrap dynamically table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build an option to add and delete rows in a table using bootstrap and asp.net. But, I'm having issues to add a DropDownList dynamically.

My view:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table id="myTable" class=" table order-list">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Payment Category</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-sm-3">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedPaymentCategory, Model.PaymentCategories, "Select a Category", new
                        {
                            @class = "form-control"
                        })
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="number" name="amount" class="form-control" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger " value="Delete">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="text-align: left;">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block " id="addrow" value="Add Row" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr></tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

The model is a simple query to get the Payment Category.
Then, I have a JS to add and remove the rows in the table:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 0;

    $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
          // HERE IS MY ISSUE. HOW CAN I CREATE THE DropDownList
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="amount' + counter + '"/></td>';

        cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger "  value="Delete"></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
        counter++;
    });



    $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        counter -= 1
    });


});



function calculateRow(row) {
    var price = +row.find('input[name^="price"]').val();

}

function calculateGrandTotal() {
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $("table.order-list").find('input[name^="price"]').each(function () {
        grandTotal += +$(this).val();
    });
    $("#grandtotal").text(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
}
```

Everything is working fine, but I don't know how can I create in the JS the DropDownList. Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `select` element:

```
cols += '<td><select> \
        <option value=“option1”>option1</option> \
        <option value=“option2”>option2</option> \
    </select></td>';
```

Comment: But the options are created by the model. They are not always the same to set it hard code

Comment: You can modify programmatically whatever is inside the option tags and add more if you want.

Comment: Hum... How can I "know" get the options content? It is inside my model (MVC)

Comment: You´ll have to create a WebService with a method that returns the ddl values. Then use AJAX to get those values in JavaScript.

Comment: Hhum... I'm new at it. I have no idea about "ddl values"

Comment: ddl = DropDownList. I mean that you should return the PaymentCategories with a WebService method so you can get them with an AJAX call.